# Airflow worker Server not using gunicorn

Tags: python, airflow, gunicorn, wsgi, airflow-scheduler

How do I get `airflow worker` to run using gunicorn rather than the flask server? By default,  `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` server seem to run using gunicorn. Hence, I would expect `airflow worker` default to be this as well. I'm using [this docker-compose file](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml) to startup airflow for context.

P.S I'm using CeleryExecutor as my Executor.

Thanks in advance.